# How the power spectral density changes under frequency scaling?

Tags: power-spectral-density, proof

Let the power spectral density PSD of a random process be

$$\phi(w) = \sum_{k = \infty}^\infty r(k)e^{-i\omega k}$$

where $\omega \in [-\pi,\pi]$ and $r(k)$ is the correlation function. I have to show that under a re-scaling of the frequency
$$\omega = \bar\omega T_s$$
the PSD changes as follows
$$\bar\phi(\bar\omega) = T_s\phi(\bar\omega T_s) = T_s\sum_kr(k)e^{-i\bar\omega T_s k}$$

My guess:
I tried to obtain an expression for $r(k)$ under the same re-scaling, if I can obtain something like $\bar r(k) = T_sr(k)$ then it is proved. So from the expression for the autocorrelation function
$$r(k) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\phi(f)e^{ifk}df = \frac{T_s}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi/T_s}^{\pi/T_s}\phi(\bar f T_s)e^{i\bar{f} T_sk}d\bar f$$

I am highly tempted to say that this is $T_s r(k)$ but I am lying to myself.

Comment: As this is some homework, the first question is, what have you tried yourself to solve it and the second one would be where are you failing in doing so? Share you thoughts etc ...

Comment: I added my guess, maybe is too naive, but I tried other things and I got even more confused.